# Passing JSON to new activity - Android app

Tags: java, android, json

This code below returns json into a textView. How do I pass the data within this textview to another activity?

```
 private void showJSON(String response){
    String name="";
    String address="";
    String vc = "";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        name = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
        address = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_ADDRESS);
        vc = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_VC);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    textViewResult.setText("Name:\t"+name+"\nAddress:\t" +address+ "\nVice Chancellor:\t"+ vc);
}
```

This is the [tutorial link](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrieve-data-from-mysql-database-in-android-using-volley/) I'm following. I know it can be done using intents but I wasn't sure how to use it in this example.

Thanks

Comment: whats the question ?

Comment: How do I pass the data I have in my TextView to another activity?

Comment: Use intents and putExtra

Comment: Would it be okay if you show me how it would work in this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the answers. This has helped me understand how to use intents    and I was able to solve my problem with this:

Activity 1

```
    String json= textViewResult.getText().toString();
    Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
    i.putExtra("Data",json);
    startActivity(i);
```

Activity 2

```
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String json = b.getString("Data");
    TextView jData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    jData.setText(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String json=textViewResult.getText().toString();
startActivity(new Intent(this,YourActivity.class).putExtra("data",json));
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was able to solve my problem in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Pass String data using putExtra

```
    Intent i = new Intent(youractivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("name",name);
    i.putExtra("address",address);
    i.putExtra("vc",vc);
    startActivity(i);
```

In SecondActivity

```
    String name=getIntent().getStringExtra("name"); 
    String address=getIntent().getStringExtra("address"); 
    String vc=getIntent().getStringExtra("vc");
```

OR

Pass json data from activity

```
     Intent i = new Intent(youractivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("jsonObject", jsonObject.toString());
     startActivity(i);
```

In SecondActivity

```
      Intent intent = getIntent();
      String jsonString = intent.getStringExtra("jsonObject");
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was able to solve my problem in a similar way.